# Response is not assignable to type Promise<any> Property finally is missing?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript, async-await

I removed async function it was like `public async ResponseHandler" but throws error Promise property finally is missing , any idea why it would happen just changing async function to regular function ?

handler.ts

```
export class AccountBalanceHandler  {
 public ResponseHandler(@Body()data: IAccountResponse  ): Promise<any> {
        return data;
    }
}
```

main.ts

```
export class GetAccountBalanceController extends Controller {


    private accountBalanceHandler: AccountBalanceHandler;

    constructor() {

        this.accountBalanceHandler = new AccountBalanceHandler();
    }

    private combineResults(data:any) : Promise<any> {
        this.accountBalanceHandler.ResponseHandler(data.Details[1]);
    }
}
```

AccountResponse.interface.ts

```
export interface IAccountResponse  {
    header: any;
    details: IDetails;
}

export interface  IDetails {
    lineOfBusiness: string;
    primary: IAccountBalanceDetails;
    secondary: IAccountBalanceDetails;
}

export interface IAccountBalanceDetails {
    balanceAccount: string;
    beginningBalance: string;
    endingBalance: string;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like a type error on your `combineResults` method.

try returning a Promise or changing your return type. e.g.

```
 private combineResults(data:any) : Promise<any> {
        return this.accountBalanceHandler.ResponseHandler(data.Details[1]);
    }
```

The return type of `public ResponseHandler` is also indicated as a promise, but you are just returning the input of `data`. I am not sure what `@Body()` does.

Comment: @Body is nothing just a tsoa tag not doing anything

Comment: oh you are saying public ResponseHandler should do something `return Promise.resolve(data)`

Comment: yes, then the method type definition and the return data type would match

Comment: also, then you can have more type safety by updating the return type to: `public ResponseHandler(@Body()data: IAccountResponse  ): Promise<IAccountResponse> {...` <-- this assumes `@Body()` doesn't transform the data type.